# Erro ao gerar Relatório no Jasper Ireports

Tags: java, relatório, ireport, jasper-reports

Segui um blog na web em que ensina a gerar os relatórios, porém me deparo com um situação que não consigo resolver.

No caso tenho os seguintes códigos:

Main.java

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().abrirRelatorioClientes();
}

public void abrirRelatorioClientes() {


    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/reportTeste.jasper" );


    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();






    try {


        ReportUtils.openReport( "reportTeste", inputStream, parametros,
                ConnectionFactory.getSakilaConnection() );

    } catch ( SQLException exc ) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( JRException exc ) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

ConnectionFactory.java

```
public class ConnectionFactory {


static {
    try {

      Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );


    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException exc ) {


        exc.printStackTrace();

    }
}


public static Connection getConnection(
        String url,
        String usuario,
        String senha ) throws SQLException {


    return DriverManager.getConnection( url, usuario, senha );

}


public static Connection getSakilaConnection() throws SQLException {

    return getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/base",
            "root",
            "root" );

}

}
```

ReportUtils.java

```
public class ReportUtils {

/**
 * Abre um relatório usando uma conexão como datasource.
 * 
 * @param titulo Título usado na janela do relatório.
 * @param inputStream InputStream que contém o relatório.
 * @param parametros Parâmetros utilizados pelo relatório.
 * @param conexao Conexão utilizada para a execução da query.
 * @throws JRException Caso ocorra algum problema na execução do relatório
 */
public static void openReport(
        String titulo,
        InputStream inputStream,
        Map<String, Object> parametros,
        Connection conexao ) throws JRException {


    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
            inputStream, parametros, conexao );


    viewReportFrame( titulo, print );

}

/**
 * Abre um relatório usando um datasource genérico.
 *
 * @param titulo Título usado na janela do relatório.
 * @param inputStream InputStream que contém o relatório.
 * @param parametros Parâmetros utilizados pelo relatório.
 * @param dataSource Datasource a ser utilizado pelo relatório.
 * @throws JRException Caso ocorra algum problema na execução do relatório
 */
public static void openReport(
        String titulo,
        InputStream inputStream,
        Map<String, Object> parametros,
        JRDataSource dataSource ) throws JRException {


    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
            inputStream, parametros, dataSource );


    viewReportFrame( titulo, print );

}


private static void viewReportFrame( String titulo, JasperPrint print ) {


    JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer( print );


    JFrame frameRelatorio = new JFrame( titulo );


    frameRelatorio.add( viewer, BorderLayout.CENTER );


    frameRelatorio.setSize( 500, 500 );


    frameRelatorio.setExtendedState( JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );


    frameRelatorio.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );


    frameRelatorio.setVisible( true );

}

}
```

Ao fazer o preview no relatório no Ireports ele aparece os dados certo.

Só que ao executar ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java:706)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:394)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:368)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2033)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:378)
at tutorialrelatorios.util.ReportUtils.openReport(ReportUtils.java:45)
at tutorialrelatorios.Main.abrirRelatorioClientes(Main.java:50)
at tutorialrelatorios.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

Pelo retorno algo esta ficando nulo ao executar o relatório, no caso baixei o exemplo do tutorial e utilizei ele no meu teste e funcionou executou sem problemas, analisei os dois XML e estão idênticos.

Não sei mais o que pode ser.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, a maneira mais fácil de encontrar o problema é debugando.

Mas eu começaria olhando duas coisas, primeiro se o seu "inputStream" não está nulo, pode ser que não tenha encontrado o arquivo do relatório e depois olharia a "connection" pode ser que não tenha conseguidon conexão com o servidor de banco de dados.